# Bezeichnung der Einwohner = Ländername

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

Im deutschen Sprachraum heißen manche Regionen so wie die Einwohner:

- In `Sachsen` leben die `Sachsen`
  Weitere Beispiele: `Niedersachsen`, `Bayern`, `Pommern`, `Hessen`, `Franken`, `Preussen`, `Schwaben`, `Westfalen`, `Böhmen`, ...

Daneben gibt es nur wenige nicht-deutsche Länder/Regionen, wo das auch der Fall ist:

- In `Ungarn` leben die `Ungarn`
- In `Polen` leben die `Polen`
- In `Schweden` leben die `Schweden`

Dazu eine Reihe von Fragen:

1. Gibt es noch weitere Länder, wo die Einwohner so heißen wie das Land?
2. Warum ist die Äquivalenz der Bezeichnung im deutschen Sprachraum die Regel, aber außerhalb nicht?
3. Gibt es einen Grund, warum gerade für die zwei Länder, deren Geschichte sehr eng mit Deutschland verwoben ist, ohne jemals Teil des Heiligen Römischen Reiches gewesen zu sein, die Bezeichnungen gleich sind?

Comment: In Schweden leben die Schweden, in Tschechien die Tschechen (fast gleich geschrieben)

Comment: Bezeichnungen dieser Art sind offenbar nicht selten, aber keine Regel. In der Pfalz wohnen die Pfälzer, in Frankfurt die Frankfurter,... Die Regel scheint nur auf die Endungen -en und -rn zuzutreffen.

Comment: @BarthZalewski: Schweden ist aufgenommen, danke. Ich wusste, dass es drei Beispiele gibt, aber eines vergessen.

Comment: @Sempie: Frankfurt würde ich nicht als Region bezeichnen. Dass Städtenamen und Stadtbewohner nicht in dieses Schema passen, ist ja klar. Was die Pfalz angeht: Es ist richtig, die Gleichheit der Namen von Einwohner und Regionen trifft nicht auf jede Region zu. Aber auf sehr viele.

Comment: @Sempie Aber nicht auf alle, denn in Brasilien leben Brasilianer und Spanien Spanier. Dort wird offensichtlich mindestens aus "-en" "-er". Bleibt zu klären, warum wir nicht "Poler" und "Schweder" sagen. Ich befürchte nur (und das geht jetzt an MERose), dass die Antwort lautet: Es ist wie es ist.

Comment: @hellcode: Das sehe ich genauso, deswegen sprach ich explizit von Regionen und nicht Bundesländern. M-V ist ja ein Kunststaat, denn Mecklenburg-Vorpommern ist erst 1945/1946 ein gemeinsames Verwaltungssubjekt. So wie Rheinland-Pfalz, Nordrhein-Westfalen, Sachsen-Anhalt, Baden-Württemberg (in den 1950er Jahren).

Comment: Ich schätze wirklich, dass das etwas mit der Endung -en zu tun hat. (Ich denke da z.B. auch an die Burgunden, die heute eher Burgunder heißen. Im Nibelungenlied wird der zugehörige Ort auch Burgunden genannt.) Ich vermute, dass oft die Orte/Regionen/Landschaften nach den dort siedelnden Völkern/Geschlechtern benannt wurden (oder doch umgekehrt??)

Comment: Finden wir solche Bezeichnungen die NICHT mit -en, -rn oder -er enden? Mir fallen auf Anhieb keine ein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diese Übereinstimmung ist nur möglich, wenn der Name der geographischen Region auf -en, -ern oder -arn endet. Denn dann kann auch der Plural der Einwohnerbezeichnung gleich enden, was zwingend notwendig ist, um die angesprochene Gleichheit herstellen zu können.

Zusätzlich muss auch die Endsilbe des Regions-Namens unbetont sein. Das trifft z.B. auf *Athen* nicht zu.

Dass diese Bedingungen aber zwar notwendig, aber keineswegs ausreichend sind, zeigen diese Beispiele bei denen das Land auf -ien endet:

- Brasilien - Brasilianer
- Italien - Italiener
- Indien - Inder
- (es gibt viel mehr -ien-Beispiele)

aber auch:

- Ägypten - Ägypter
- Jemen - Jemeniten
- Litauen - Litauer

Dass gerade geographische Namen aus dem deutschen Sprachraum in dieses Muster fallen, erklärt sich dadurch, dass die Plurale der Einwohnerbezeichnungen *immer* den Regeln der deutschen Pluralbildung unterliegen, während die Namen der Regionen aber meist nur dann Regeln der deutschen Sprache entsprechen, wenn sie im deutschen Sprachgebiet entstanden sind. Das ist natürlich besonders häufig dann der Fall, wenn diese Regionen im deutschen Sprachraum liegen.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man sich die Herkunft von Landes- und Volksbezeichnungen ansieht, dann stellt man Folgendes fest:

- Es gibt sowohl Ländernamen, die vom Namen ihrer (möglicherweise ehemaligen) Bewohner abgeleitet sind ("Franken" = "das Land, wo der Stamm der Franken wohnt"), als auch Bewohnernamen, die vom Namen ihres Landes abgeleitet sind ("Engländer" = "die Bewohner von England").
- Der erste der beiden Fälle ist im deutschen Sprachraum und in der unmittelbaren Umgebung relativ häufig; er wird umso seltener, je weiter man sich von Mitteleuropa entfernt. Das ist historisch zu erklären: Die Stämme der Franken, Sachsen oder Schwaben existierten lange, bevor sie ein festes Territorium ihr Eigen nennen konnten.
- Alle genannten Beispiele, wo der Regionsname gleich dem Plural des Einwohnernamens ist, gehören in die erste Gruppe.(*) Anscheinend ist es im Deutschen nicht üblich, aus einem Regionsnamen auf "-en" oder "-rn" einen Bewohnernamen auf "-e"(Sg.)/"-en"(Pl.) bzw. "-r"(Sg.)/"-rn"(Pl.) zu bilden, während ein Bewohnername auf "-e"(Sg.)/"-en"(Pl.) oder "-r"(Sg.)/"-rn"(Pl.) zum Regionsnamen werden kann ("Sachsen" (Volksstamm) -> "das Land der Sachsen" -> "Sachsen" (Region)).

Ich habe allerdings keine Ahnung, warum das in manchen Fällen (z. B. "Friesen", "Dänen") nicht passiert ist.

(*) Nachtrag: "Böhmen" scheint eine Ausnahme zu sein. Das Wort bezeichnete wohl zunächst die Landschaft (Boiohaemum = Heim der Boier, eines keltischen Stammes) und erst später deren Bewohner.

Comment: Das ist eine interessante These, wonach der Ländernamen mit dem Bewohnernamen zusammenfällt, wenn es zuerst einen Bewohnernamen gab, aber noch kein ihnen final zugehöriges Land. Demnach müssten Länder, deren Bewohner schon in der Völkerwanderungszeit einen Namen hatten, häufiger in denselben Namen tragen wie die Völker, als für Land-Volk-Kombinationen jüngeren Datums. Das erklärt natürlich, warum wir diese Regel nur in europäischen Ländern beobachten. Die These ließe sich erhärten, wenn man wüsste, welche Völker wanderten und später in Gegenden sesshaft wurden, die heute noch existieren.

Comment: Aber natürlich kann die Entstehung von Namen kompliziert sein. Zwar wohnen Franken in Franken, aber auch irgendwie auch in Frankreich und dann heißen sie Franzosen. Und die Engländer wohnen in England, dem Land der Angeln, sind also eigentlich solche.

Comment: Nicht nur bei den Böhmen funktioniert die Zuordnung nicht ganz so direkt, sondern auch bei den Polen. Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polen#Landesname) ist das Land nach dem Stamm der Polanen benannt, erst später wurde aus dem Landesnamen auch eine Bezeichnung der Einwohner. Trotzdem halte ich die These hier für schlüssiger und tiefgreifender als die der akzeptierten Antwort. Interessant wäre tatsächlich noch, ob es Faktoren gab, die Ländernamen auf "-land" begünstigten, wie bei Irland, Schottland, Finnland, Friesland, die m.W. auch alle nach ihren Einwohnern benannt sind.